# Using fetchone on a select query in python 3, syntax confusion

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to set up a register function on my site and I am stuck on setting up the logic for querying the database to see if the username exists. If it does it should return the apology page.

This is my code:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Stored POST data to variables
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        confirmation = request.form.get('confirmation')

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not username:
           return apology("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password and confirmation were both submitted
        elif not password:
            return apology("must provide password in both fields", 403)

        # Ensure passwords match
        elif confirmation != password:
            return apology("passwords do not match", 403)

        elif db.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?', 
        (username,)).fetchone()  is not None:
            return apology("Username already exists", 403)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
elif db.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?', 
(username,)).fetchone()  is not None:
TypeError: execute() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have seen code where they first use a cursor() method but I thought the execute() method does this in python 3? Would you please assist with my database query, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem was stemming from my db connection. so the .execute() syntax was different to the standard documentation.

I changed the following:

```
from cs50 import SQL; and
db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")
```

to:

```
import sqlite3; and
db = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
```

Hopefully this helps somebody else out there in the world doing the same pset and not wanting to use the abbreviated cs50 library. The syntax to my query statement above was correct.

```
    elif db.execute('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?', 
    (username,)).fetchone()  is not None:
        return apology("Username already exists", 403)
```